# Spring Command Object attributes replaced in concurrent scenario

Tags: java, spring-mvc, concurrency, yui

I am sending several asynchronous requests using YUI2 Connect utils to a Spring 2 Web MVC web app. The request asks for a calculation result for an Id. The receiving method in my controller has some long running operations to calculate a result for the given ID in the requests. When logging client and server I realized that results on server side did not match the results on the client side, i.e. results on client side where matched with different ids than they were on server side. I found the problem to be that the id's get mixed up in the controller method.

The client method looks like this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 var request = YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('GET', myURL+ array[i],
  myCallback);
}
```

The controller method looks something like this.

```
public ModelAndView calculate(HttpServletRequest request,
        Command command, BindException errors) throws Exception {
  MyCommand myCommand = (MyCommand) command;
  //myCommand object contains id from request, used in both operations
  Result1 result1 = doLongRunningOperation(myCommand);
  //now the id in myCommand is different from the beginning but not
  //changed in the operation above
  Result2 result2 = doAnotherLongRunningOperation(result1);
  return buildModelAndView(result2);
}
```

I assumed Spring would handle this scenario in a thread-safe way, but it looks different here. Is there a configuration for this that I missed? I currently handle it by deep copying the command object, which works, but this shouldn't be the way to go, right?

Comment: I cannot see how id and result are declare. You must only use local variable in controller methods.

Comment: the id is sent in the request and retrieved from the command object, the result is calculated in a thread safe environment

Comment: I can see `id = myCommand.getId();`. What I meant is that I would haved written `int id = myCommand.getId();` for `id` to be local to the method.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. actually I just pass the command as a parameter to the operations. they are legacy methods which only perform a get on the command object. however, in the second operation the id in the command object is a different one, which means it was replaced by spring binding process

Comment: The code you show will only compile if id is an attribute of your controller. Please tell me how the variable id is defined.

Comment: please see my latest edit. id is part of the command object as resolved by spring binding process

Comment: As `command` is a parameter of the request, each thread treating a different request will have its own. But you seem to pass it to another method or at least do computations on it. Double check in your code if you do not modify command. Try to log as many times as necessary the value of id to see exactly where it is changed. You could also try to use a debugger, stop at beginning of the method, let another request pass and then single step your code to see when id is changed. Without seeing the whole code (and I suppose it is large :-( ), I cannot say much more ...

Comment: thanks, I will try again. However, I logged the command object and it  always had the same hash, therefore I assume it was not a new one each time. Is there a configuration for that?